# Simulate Battery State

Tags: android, batterymanager

I am creating an activity which seeks to change the state of LEDs on a device. The LED behavior is handled through an embedded controller with no APIs exposed, so I cannot directly change the state of the LEDs. The state changes based on the charging and battery percentage state of the device. Is there any way for me to simulate a different battery level/charging state via Android Studio to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

With your emulator opened, just click on this button:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response, can I do this with a physical device I am debugging on? I seek to do it programatically to create test code with it.

Comment: I think you can't

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust the battery level on an emulator in the settings.

[image: android emulator settings]

Comment: Thank you for the response, can I do this with a physical device I am debugging on? I seek to do it programatically to create test code with it

Comment: You're not going to be able to do this on a physical device short of hacking your own kernel together. If you're looking to write test code, you should mock the responses from sensors anyway. Just implement a mock service to serve up the battery status to your tests.